# Date value retrieved from an item keep on increasing every few seconds

Tags: 2013, javascript, splistitem

I was trying to retrieve items from a SharePoint custom list called "Some Events" using JSOM.

Title, Venue, EventDate were few fields I was retrieving. Every thing worked fine except EventDate.

```
event.get_item('EventDate');
```

I used above JavaScript code to get value, but to my surprise this value of Date  kept on increasing every few seconds to such an extent that in next 5 or more seconds the entire Date got changed.

**Also this happened only in IE**. I checked on chrome and ff, things were fine.

I checked in Developer tool and add watch to this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer is very specific about the key words used.

```
event.get_item('EventDate');
```

In above code there was a problem. the keyword "event" was the main culprit.

Once I changed the code to

```
eventDetails.get_item('EventDate');
```

Everything worked fine.

So from this incidence I have stopped using keywords such as "event", "id" etc. which might have been used by IE for some or other purpose.